# How do you pass data from old JavaScript app into an angular 6 app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am working on components for what will later be a single page app, but as a stop gap measure I am trying to retrofit the angular 6 component (an editor component) into a traditional JavaScript/jquery app.

Basically I want to add a link in the existing app that triggers display of the new editor and loads a specific record to be edited. Then when done they can save the pop over closes and they can do the same thing with a different record.

I know this would be easy with angular 1,  and not how ng6 was intended, but like I said, trying to get components usable as I go and then comeback to the monolith for repair.

Any suggestions would be great, most search yield angular1 results or nothing helpful to this end.

Comment: Try accessing/importing js file in components.

Comment: No quite sure what you are suggesting or how that relates... I can import a JS file. but how do I connect it?  So for instance... this application has an advanced scheduling interface written in old school javascript. we are looking to add a link to the actions menu of each job on the schedule to bring up a route editor. That editor needs to be seeded with the job id so it can then ask the server for the data to edit. That editor I intend will load once and then I can send a message into it saying "load job 14" then the next job that's clicked say "load Job 15"

Comment: I think if I really wanted to hack around this I could put the load data into session or local storage and then have the angular app watch for changes... or maybe find a way to pass in as an attribute then load and destroy the app each time but non of those are appealing...

Comment: ultimately I am hoping for a something where I can create some sort of rxjs, observable, or pubsub like event system that I can export or expose and then the other app can sent an event in with the data and the app can respond. Not sure how to do that or if it's possible....